# How to hide tabs in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my activity I have three fragments. I am using `viewpager` and `SlidingTabLayout` to show them. I want to ask is there any way to hide tabs layout from action bar in fragments?

i have a function,

```
 @Override
        public void toggledFullscreen(boolean fullscreen)
        {
            if (fullscreen)
            {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs =getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes();
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                attrs.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
                getActivity().getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
                {
                    //noinspection all
                    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
                }
            }
```

but this does not hide tabs layout.

Please help.

Comment: could you post ur xml file?

Comment: MainActivity or Fragment?

Comment: you can try to set the visibility of SlidingTabsLayout to invisible to hide them .

Comment: any examples please?

Comment: Won't it be producing NPE  if i call SlidingTabsLayout to hide in fragments?